# SPD: calculated column with data from another list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm in the same situation described [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295567/how-to-create-calculated-column-with-data-from-another-list).

I'm trying to use *Create List Item* and *Update List Item* actions (like suggested in the answer) but without any results.

Could someone kindly explain the procedure mentioned in the answer?

Thank you,

Marcello

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer there, but here is a copy in case it gets deleted or removed:

lem.mallari's answer is a huge pain unless you can assume that the Amounts in List A never change, since it's not tracking whether an item has already been added to the sum. There is no way for a Workflow to iterate through a SharePoint list, which means there is no easy way to calculate the sum or average of multiple list items.

The correct way to implement this will will require some development. The SharePoint Developer Training ([2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/ee513147), [2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/fp123633)) will actually get you most of the way there: an event receiver should trigger when items are added or changed in Lists A and B that uses SharePoint's API to go through List A and average values by Name, then update all (or just affected) items in List B. Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to display the sum of all entries in List A that have the same name as the item in List B as long as all the data is displayed on your page. If you're handy with XPath and InfoPath, you could add List A as a secondary data source to List B's form and select only applicable items in List A to sum from.

But if we're talking Workflows, here's the "workflow only" method. This was tested and successful in 2010. Create custom List C with the following columns:

- Title (string, mandatory, enforce unique values)
- TotalItems (integer, mandatory, default 0)
- Sum (number, decimal places however you want, mandatory, default 0)
- Average (calculated, =IF(TotalItems=0,0,Sum/TotalItems)) (optional)

Replace the Name columns in Lists A and B with lookup columns pointing at List C. Delete the Amount column in List B, instead including the Sum column as an additional column. Add the following columns to List A, and ensure that users cannot change them directly. This can be restricted by making InfoPath forms or by making alternative view and edit forms.

- AmountArchive (number, identical to Amount, default 0)
- AmountHasBeenSubmitted (yes/no, default no)

Create a Workflow to run each time an item is created or modified in List A. Use these commands (I'm using a list for readability; it was getting ugly when formatted as code):

- If Current Item:Amount not equals Current Item:AmountArchive

  - Set Variable:Item Count to (Data source: List C; Field from source: TotalItems; Find the List Item: Field Title; Value: Current Item:Name(Return field as: Lookup Value (as Text)))
  - Calculate Variable:ItemCount plus 1 (Output to Variable: ItemCount)
  - Calculate List C:Sum (similar settings as above; be sure to use Lookup Value (as Text) and not String!) minus Current Item:AmountArchive (Output to Variable: SumWithoutValue)
  - Calculate Variable: SumWithoutValue plus Current Item:Amount (Output to Variable: NewSum)
  - If Current Item:AmountHasBeenSubmitted equals No

    - Set AmountHasBeenSubmitted to Yes
    - Update item in List C (Set TotalItems to Variable:ItemCount; Set Sum to Variable:NewSum; Find the List Item in the same way of Field:Title; Value: Current Item:Name(Return field as: Lookup Value (as Text))
  - Else

    - Update item in List C (don't do anything to TotalItems; use the same logic to set Sum to Variable:NewSum)
  - Set Amount to Current Item:AmountArchive